# Ruby symbol syntax with strings ex "a-b": "d"

Tags: ruby

Starting in ruby 1.9 you could use the new syntax for symbols inside of hashes

Before 1.9

```
{:a => 'b'}
```

1.9 and later

```
{a:'b'}
```

But why isn't there a similar thing for symbols that contain strings that cannot be easily converted `{:"a-b" => 'c'}` like

```
{"a-b": 'c'}
```

Is there something in the Ruby lexical parser that would prevent this from happening? or fundamental reason why this was not also implemented?

Comment: For strings, it they are "clean", ruby automatically translates them into symbols. :"a" becomes :a . The aliased convention (:a => 3 ~ a: 3) is only for symbols, not for strings prior to translating into symbols. This is intentional, because in the case you state, :"a-b" => 'c' is not a valid assignment (parsed-> :a -b => 'c'). In the case the string is not clean, then it displays as a symbol (:"a-b"), but "a-b" is not actually a string, it's just an annotation.

Comment: @John You are already confused by yourself. The key in `{:"a-b" => 'c'}` is not a string, it is a symbol.

Comment: @RubyRacer: Not quite. The JavaScript-style symbol-as-a-hash-key notation is only available for symbols that also qualify as labels so you can't say `@a: b`, `$a: b`, and various other things that work fine with the standard symbol syntax and hashrocket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Matz decided against it:

> Iff {'key': 'value'} means {:key => 'value'} I have no objection.
>
> [but later on...]
>
> The discussion has gone away in the wind without making any consensus.
>   So I marked this 'rejected'. My point is clearly stated in the first comment.

Cited from https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4801